# Were there interstate tariffs before the US Constitution (1789)?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, trade, colonial-america

I've heard many times that the [Commerce Clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commerce_Clause) of the US Constitution was (in part) designed to end tariffs between the thirteen states.  Now that I'm trying to learn about those tariffs, I'm having a very hard time finding any information about them at all.

- Were there tariffs charged on goods moving between states in the US before 1789?
- How about before 1776, between the thirteen colonies?

(I'm expecting the answers to be *yes* (regarding the states) and *no* (regarding the colonies), but I have no evidence at this time.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer appears to be "yes" in both cases:

[Tariffs in United States history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariffs_in_United_States_history#Colonial_Era_to_1789):

> In the colonial era, before 1775, nearly every colony levied its own
>   tariffs, usually with lower rates for British products. There were
>   taxes on ships (on a tonnage basis), import taxes on slaves, export
>   taxes on tobacco, and import taxes on alcoholic beverages. The
>   London government insisted on a policy of mercantilism whereby only
>   British ships could trade in the colonies. In defiance, some American
>   merchants engaged in smuggling.
>
> During the Revolution, the British blockade from 1775 to 1783 largely
>   ended foreign trade. In the 1783–89 period, each state set up its own
>   trade rules, often imposing tariffs or restrictions on neighboring
>   states. The new Constitution, which went into effect in 1789, banned
>   interstate tariffs or trade restrictions, as well as state taxes on
>   exports.

The prevailing doctrine of [Mercantilism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercantilism) advocated free internal trade and high external tariffs, so the Commerce Clause was an important indicator that the US was a single country.